# RecyclerView doesn't update its view but List is updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerView to show list of available apps in device..moreover I am using bottomSheet to show more details about selected app ...in this section, I place uninstall button ...here I use uninstall code and from *onActivityResult method in BottomSheetDialog.kt file* ... on OK pressed ....I want to delete that app/item from list and update View....here list is correct in coding but recyclerView doesn't update its list

> Note: I debug the code and found that list got updated in BottomSheet File...I comment out that ....but
> recyclerView doesn't

---

I searched on internet, but didn't find solution which fits in my case

---

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   
    
    recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(applicationList) // here I send mutable list of all apps in device to adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


private fun getApps(List: MutableList<ResolveInfo>): MutableList<AppData> {
     // here I return list to adapter with details of installed apps like icon, name, packageName etc
    }
```

**DataClass**

```
data class AppData(
val icon: Drawable,
val name: String,
val packageName: String
.....
.....)
```

**Adapter.kt**

```
class Adapter(private val listOfApps: MutableList<AppData>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {
 // here I receive mutableList in constructor of Adapter

class ViewHolder(appView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(appView), View.OnClickListener,
    View.OnLongClickListener {

    init { // initiate both click listeners
        appView.setOnClickListener(this)
        appView.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    }
    // call elements from activity.xml
    val icon: ImageView = appView.App_icon
    val name: TextView = appView.App_name
    val size: TextView = appView.App_size

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        Toast.makeText(v?.context, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(currentItem, appList) 
        // send currentItem and all List to BottomSheetDialog to show details with the help of function 
       
        // Show bottomSheet on LongPress
        return true
    }

    
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder // done

override fun getItemCount() = listOfApps.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val currentItem = listOfApps[position]
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(currentItem.icon) 
    holder.name.text = currentItem.name
    holder.size.text = currentItem.size
  }
```

**BottomSheetDialog.kt** ...... here in onActivtyResult I delete item and call notify method ... problem is here

```
class BottomSheetDialog(private val appData: AppData, private val appList: MutableList<AppData>) :
BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
 // here I receive appData and AppList in constructor from Adapter OnLongPress

override fun onCreateView() // done
    
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      
   // here when bottomSheet popup and on click of uninstall.....I check whether user click on OK or CANCEL in onActivity Method (overidden below)
   
     Uninstall_App.setOnClickListener {
        // permission in manifest added
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("package:${appData.packageName}")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }

    
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    // get result from uninstall dialog
    if (resultCode == -1) { // ok pressed
        Toast.makeText(context, "ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        dismiss()

       // here when user pressed OK....delete that item from List
        val index = appList.indexOf(appData)
        appList.removeAt(index)
        Adapter(appList).notifyItemRemoved(index)
        Adapter(appList).notifyDataSetChanged()
        
        // I check above three line by debugging it 
        // 1. val index .. return index of current item
        // 2. this line remove that item
        // 3. Adapter(appList) .... notify Item removed 
        // 4. here that indexed item is removed but view is not updated
        // Note: if it is wrong which is the best method to do this 

    } else if (resultCode == 0) { // cancel pressed
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cancel Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

these lines

```
Adapter(appList).notifyItemRemoved(index)
Adapter(appList).notifyDataSetChanged()
```

are both creating new adapters, notify them and.. thats all. they aren't attached to any `RecyclerView` (as you do in `onCreate`), so won't be drawn anywhere

you should notify adapter already set for `RecyclerView` - keep reference in `Activity` and refer to it instead of creating new one

Comment: can you please share a code...I am stuck.......notifyItemRemoved(index) didn't called itself in onActivityResut

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "notifyItemRemoved(index) didn't called itself"... just create some interface or public method in `Activity` and refer throu to adapter attached to `RecyclerView` instead of creating new one

Answer (score 0):

What you did here is created **two new adapters** (that have no relation to the adapter used by recycler view except the type of adapter is the same):

```
Adapter(appList).notifyItemRemoved(index)
Adapter(appList).notifyDataSetChanged()
```

You can create an interface to listen for changes from `BottomSheetDialog`:

```
interface OnAppDeletedListener {
    fun appDeletedAtIndex(index: Int)
}
```

Update your `BottomSheetDialog` to accept an additional argument of type `OnAppDeletedListener`:

```
class BottomSheetDialog(private val appData: AppData, private val appList: MutableList<AppData>, private val listener: OnAppDeletedListener) :
    BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    
    ...
        
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val index = appList.indexOf(appData)
            listener.appDeletedAtIndex(index)  
            dismiss() 
        }
    }
}
```

Update your adapter. **It must not be responsible for showing any dialogues**. Activity or Fragment is responsible for that.

```
class Adapter(private val listOfApps: MutableList<AppData>, private val longClickListener: View.OnLongClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {
     // here I receive mutableList in constructor of Adapter

    class ViewHolder(appView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(appView), View.OnClickListener {

        init { // initiate both click listeners
            appView.setOnClickListener(this)
            appView.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener)
        }
        // call elements from activity.xml
        val icon: ImageView = appView.App_icon
        val name: TextView = appView.App_name
        val size: TextView = appView.App_size

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(v?.context, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
     }
}
```

And update your activity code:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: Adapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       
        val longClickListener = object: View.OnLongClickListener {
                override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
                    displayAppInfoDialog()
                    return true
                }
            }
        adapter = Adapter(applicationList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    private fun displayAppInfoDialog() {
        val listener = object: OnAppDeletedListener() {
                fun appDeletedAtIndex(index: Int) {
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
                }
            }
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(currentItem, appList, listener)
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you are not updating the existing Adapter, you are instead creating two new instances.

Replace this line:

```
recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(applicationList) // here I send mutable list of all apps in device to adapter
```

With

```
this.adapter = Adapter(applicationList)
recyclerView.adapter = this.adapter
```

Also add `val adapter: Adapter?` to your class.

Now you have a reference to the adapter the RecyclerView has.

Finally, when you want to "update" it:

```
       // here when user pressed OK....delete that item from List
        val index = appList.indexOf(appData)
        appList.removeAt(index)
        Adapter(appList).notifyItemRemoved(index)
        Adapter(appList).notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Should become...

```
       // here when user pressed OK....delete that item from List
        val index = appList.indexOf(appData)
        appList.removeAt(index)
        
        this.adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

**IMPORTANT CAVEAT**: There are other issues here with the separation of concerns in your code, but among them, the fact that the `appList` you use here, is a local list; does it contain the items from `applicationList` (the one you used **when you created the adapter**)? If it doesn't then you need to *expose* said list so you can either modify it/replace it, etc.

The Adapter does NOT manage the list for you, it merely uses it to *adapt* each item to a ViewHolder. If you modify the list the adapter has, and you tell it that you inserted an item at certain position, etc. All the adapter does is (a lot behind the scenes) and "re-binds" the view at that position (if it's visible) with the new data.